# Screen resultion not right when I create a full screen WPF application in windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a WPF windows 8 desktop application that only needs to work a full HD screen ( 1920 x 1080 ).

So I set up my mainWindow to fit these ratios. But then it only fills a part of my screen.

Then I figured to check the screen width and screen height visual studios output using this code

```
        double height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
        double width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

        MessageBox.Show(height.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(width.ToString());
```

And it outputs 864x1536

But I'm 100 procent sure my screen is 1920 x 1080, I can see it if I right click on desktop and go to change screen resolution.

This is my code for full screen

```
  <Window x:Class="app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:app"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    WindowStyle="None"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Background="White" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize"  
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    >
```

Anyone know whats causing this ?

Edit: I'm a windows 8 pro 32 bit machine with a samsung 24 inch full HD screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check your display settings. Maybe they are set to use two displays (monitors) and your screen is secondary now (but primary is set to 1536x864). I mean [this settings](http://images.pcworld.com/images/article/2012/07/intel-11389049.jpg).